# swift Xcode 6 unwind segue action doesn't fire

Tags: swift, modal-dialog, action, segue, xcode6

[image: I have a primary view controller ("Main") embedded in navigation and tab bar controller presenting a modal view controller ("Modal") embedded in a navigation controller.]

"Done" button of the modally presented controller ("Modal") is bound to an exit action defined in the primary controller ("Main"):

```
@IBAction func done(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

"Done" button is not firing!

I have tried the manual segue approach from [Unwind Segue in Xcode 6 Beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960900/unwind-segue-in-xcode-6-beta-4) and bound the "Done" button action to following code in "Modal":

```
@IBAction func donePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("unwind", sender: self)
}
```

it doesn't work too!

if I remove tab bar controller everything is working fine - is that a bug or a restriction?

P.S.There is an annoying log output I can't get rid of:

```
2014-08-17 16:14:15.380 SwiftPhotoCards[9113:497540] 17545849:_UIScreenEdgePanRecognizerEdgeSettings.edgeRegionSize=13.000000
```

no idea whether it is related to the issue or not but I thought it's worth mentioning it.

Comment: Did you try with Xcode 6 beta 6? Did you try with a pure new Swift project? Unwind segues are normally fixed with Xcode 6 beta 5. I was able to set an Unwind segue (`@IBAction func done(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {}`) in a new Swift Master-Detail application project with Xcode 6 beta 6.

Comment: It doesn't work in beta 6 too. I ended changing the type of segue from modal to popover and now it works as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 12):

I've been struggling with what may be the same issue (although I'm using a Split View instead of a Tab Bar) and was able to resolve it by setting the Modal segue to "Presentation: Current Context" instead of "Default" in the Attributes Inspector:

[image]

(This is the setting on the Segue arrow that creates "Main" to "Navigation Controller" in your screenshot).

Comment: You sir, are the man. Actually... I partially take that back. Using a tab bar controller it ends up presenting with the tabs on the bottom... ugh apple...

Comment: This isn't limited to Swift.  I am having problems with an unwind segue from a modal segue using regular Obj-C.  The workaround posted by @payton works, but as reported by the previous comment, the tabs show up on the bottom allowing the user to navigate away from a view that is supposed to be modal.