# Unwind seg programmatically in Xcode6 and Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In destination screen, I put this:

```
@IBAction func unwindToLogin (segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

From storyboard view button for example, I can easily refer to this to unwind.

But I cannot do it programmatically. I tried to trigger this in current screen:

```
 performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToLogin", sender: nil)
```

but it crashes because of nil. So it seems from storyboard "exit" I can 'catch' the unwind and link it to a button, but I can't do this programmatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unwind Segue in Xcode 6 Beta 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960900/unwind-segue-in-xcode-6-beta-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the function you put in the destination view controller is not the identifier of the segue. You need to set the identifier in the storyboard, and use that string in performSegueWithIdentifier.

[image]

Comment: Could be this, but when you don't do it programmatically it catches the name of the function automatically. I thought it would be same programmatically. I don't see how you set an identified on storyboard for an unwind code, that is just a performSegueWithIdentifier function.

Comment: @RobertBrax, you select the segue in the scene list, and set the identifier in the attributes inspector. When you don't do it programmatically (like from a button), you don't need an identifier at all, it's not that " it catches the name of the function automatically".

Comment: thanks, but unwind segue do not show in scene list. @IBAction func unwindToLogin (segue : UIStoryboardSegue) {} defines the unwind and that doesn't show there

Comment: @RobertBrax, if you've made your segue, it should show up in the scene list, as I show in my update.

Comment: Ok thanks got it. Problem was in creating the unwind set. I did what I read in other message: ctrl drag from yellow controller icon, to its own exit icon, then selected there the unwind function I wanted. Then I was able to set the unwind seg with identifier as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use`Selector`s:

```
Selector("unwindToLogin:")
```

By the way, `Selector`s should be automatically created from `string`s, so I think the problem is with the missing semicolon, but I haven't my Mac with me atm.

Comment: `performSegueWithIdentifier(Selector("unwindToLogin:"), sender: nil)`

Comment: thats what I tried but got Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '($T3, sender: NilLiteralConvertible)'

Comment: Compiler messages are often not very useful in swift. Try to break code in 2 lines: `let methodSel = Selector("unwindToLogin:"); performSegueWithIdentifier(methodSel, sender: nil)`